# Fail to finish the color-changing potion?

Tags: kings-quest

**Is it possible to not finish the teeth-whitening potion?**

It seems implied, based on the achievements and general setup of the quests that there are three optional quests in the game - one for each of the townsfolk:

> Help Amaya the blacksmith prevent wolves from getting into the city.
>  Help Wente the baker not get stung by bees on his romantic picnic.
>  Help The Hobblepots finish their teeth-whitening potion.
>  These three tasks, when completed together, gain you the *Helping Hat* achievement.

...and, it seems that each of these acts changes the ending screen, as do all of your major decisions in the game:

> Preventing the wolves from entering will show an award patch on Amaya.
>  Preventing Wente from getting stung will show him without big welts on his face.
>  Finishing the potions for the Hobblepots will show gleaming sparkles by their teeth.

However, this pattern seems to have a contradiction, as it seems impossible to complete the game without finishing the potion.

> The potion is used to bypass the hypnotic powder during the Duel of Wits at the end of the game.

As such, I cannot determine any way to fail this particular quest.  The other two **can be failed**, so I figured that **this one could be too**, but there would need to be some sort of alternate solution to the puzzle mentioned.

**Is there a way to beat the game without completing the potion?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, it is possible to not complete this quest.**

While it is not possible to avoid giving the Hobblepots the frog, one can **decide to not give them the sleeping leaf ingredient** in exchange for the hypnotic powder - **the leaf can be used for the same purpose as the powder** directly in the main quest, and the potion still works later for changing the color of things, but it doesn't solve their tooth-color dilemma.